# Schrödinger equation obtain $ψ(x,t)$ from $ψ(x,0)$

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform, time-evolution

In [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/350799/328424) of the post "Wave packet expression and Fourier transforms" it is said that for the S.E. we have this property:

- If we start with an initial profile $ψ(x,0)=e^{ikx}$, then the solution to our wave equation is $ψ(x,t)=e^{i(kx−ω_kt)}$, where $ω_k$ is a constant that may depend on $k$.

I would like if someone can explain to know how we can obtain $ψ(x,t)$ from $ψ(x,0)$ in (or with the help of) the S.E.

EDIT: My first attempt was to compose the $ψ(x)$ function with an $f$ function defined as follow $f(u,t) = \frac{u}{k}-\frac{\omega t}{k}$ but I don't think it's possible in math to compose a function of one variable with another function of two variables, is it?

Comment: Possible interpretation: given the initial profile you find the one at later times by performing a convolution with the modes of the SE (i.e. the waves that satisfy the dispersion relation $\omega=\omega(k)$) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_relation

Answer (score 1):

Just plug $\psi(x,t)= e^{i(k x-\omega t)}$ into your translation-invariant wave equation and read off what $\omega(k)$ has to be to satisfy it.

For example the free Schrodinger equation
$$
i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi= -\frac{\hbar^2 }{2m}\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}
$$
gives
$$
\hbar \omega e^{i(k x-\omega t)}= \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}k^2 e^{i(k x-\omega t)}, 
$$
so
$$
\hbar \omega(k) = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}k^2.
$$

Comment: My teacher says something like that: "Since the Schroedinger Equation is **first order** in time, if you know the wave function at one time, and you solve it, you get the wave function at any time". Do you know what he means by that?

Comment: He means that if $\psi(x,t=0)= \sum_i c_n \psi_n(x)$ with $\psi_n$ an energy eigenfunction  with energy $E_n$, then $\psi(x,t)=   \sum_n c_n \psi_n(x)e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}$.

Comment: And do you know why it is possible? (the same applies for the continuous case: if $\Psi(x,0)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}} \int dp\Phi(p)e^{ipx/\hbar}$ then $\Phi(x,t)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}} \int dp\Phi(p)e^{i(px/\hbar-\omega(p)t)}$ isn't it)

Comment: Yes. It's just basic spectral theory. Remember that the eigenfunctions of a self-adjoint operator form a *complete set.*